# Looking for a book where a boy is at school and is confronted by a guidance counselor who is a monster

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book quite a few years ago about a boy who is at school and is confronted by a guidance counselor who is a monster trying to kill him.

He is saved by a girl who has been watching him and flies him away to a land where his family used to live hidden in an unreachable mountain realm. There, he finds out that everyone has ancient powers, as well as his parents at one time; but the memories were altered to save their lives in the normal world

Also at this place there is a large reflection pool whose surface can be changed to show the past. This boy has a destiny to find something hidden by one of his ancestors

Comment: The first part sounds a bit like a story out of the Goosebumps series, although the second half not so much

Comment: There is also a whiff of a resemblance to the [_Percy Jackson_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percy_Jackson_%26_the_Olympians) series, but that wouldn't be it either.

Comment: And the *[My Teacher is an Alien](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Teacher_Is_an_Alien)* series.  Apparently, it was a popular theme.

Comment: the name of the book is destiny of a dreamer by phillip marshall

Answer (score 5):

I recently found the book that I was hunting for.  It is *[Destiny of a Dreamer](https://www.betterworldbooks.com/product/detail/9781466308664?shipto=US&curcode=USD)* by Phillip Marshall.

[image: Front cover of Destiny of a Dreamer]

> Destiny of a Dreamer(Book One of The Saga of the Bruadair Clan)Felix Brody is about to begin his Awakening. It all begins one night in a dream, where Felix finds himself on a black sand beach. There, he meets a mysterious girl, named Eleanor Avierie. Eleanor explains that she was sent to Felix to tell him the truth about the existence of the Dreamwalkers and the many plains of the Dream Realms. Felix learns that his ability to remain conscious in his dreams is a sign that, he too, is a Dreamwalker. After Felix travels with Eleanor to the dream realm of Vallisdenebula, it is revealed to Felix that he will play a vital role in leading the final battle against the Nightmarewalkers and their barbaric Nightmare King, Tromluiki. For Felix is destined to discover and wield a weapon of great power, known as, the Golden Wheel of Taranis. But before Felix is ready to wield the Golden Wheel, he must train with the Shamans of the Crystal Caves, and he must meet his Spirit Guide in the Realm of the Pueblo. A long journey awaits him. A journey to far off lands and beyond...

Thank you to all who showed interest.